# Reading serial port Lua too slow linux

Tags: linux, lua, port

I am trying to read the output of a sensor through a serial port using Lua. The problem is that the rate is too slow which causes issues in my data processing steps.

Initially I wanted to use the function **popen** with the **cat** command, but I couldn't read the output because the port sends continuously data.

So then I am used the **io.read()** function where I specify the number of bytes and then get a response. But calling the function read what slows down the process. Even if I just listen to 1 byte, it can take to more than 1 sec to get a response.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the code instead of describing it in your own words.

Comment: `it can take to more than 1 sec to get a response` - In other words, you want to get a quick response if there is no data to be read?